Mean Value Theorem for Integrals Proof
In the proof of the MVT for integrals, I reach a slightly different conclusion:
Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ (with $a \neq b$) then there exists $c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)=\dfrac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$
Proof:
Apply the Extreme Value Theorem: Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ attains absolute max value $M=f(k)$ and absolute min value $m=f(p)$ for some $k,p \in [a,b]$.
Thus for all $x\in [a,b]$ it holds that:
$m \le f(x) \le M \iff \int_a^b m dx \le \int_a^b f(x) dx \le \int_a^b M dx \iff m \le \dfrac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx \le  M $
Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem: Consider the number $N=\dfrac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$.
It holds that $m\le N \le M \iff f(k) \le N \le f(p)$.
Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is also continuous on interval $[k,p]$ (or on inteval $[p,k]$ without loss of generality).
By applying the IVT on interval $[k,p]$, there exists $c \in [k, p]$ s.t. $f(c) = N$
i.e. there exists $c \in [k, p]$ s.t. $f(c) = \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx$ and the MVT for integrals is proven.
Conclusion: The number $c$ can be found in $[k,p]$ (or $[p,k]$), which is potentially (but not strictly) narrower than the interval $[a,b]$.
Naturally, if $c \in [k,p]$ then $c \in [a,b]$ as well, since $[k,p] \subseteq [a,b]$.
Is the above conclusion correct or have I misinterpreted something?
To complicate the situation a bit more, I can prove the MVT for integrals using the MVT for derivatives on $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$.
By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $F(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$.
Thus we can apply the MVT for derivatives:
Since $F$ is continuous continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ there exists $c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $F'(c) = \dfrac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a} \iff f(x) = \dfrac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx $.
In this proof the value $c$ is found in $(a,b)$, which is strictly narrower than $[a,b]$.

If you want to use the "MVT for derivatives" you have to proof $F'(x)=f(x)$ without using the "MVT for integrals". Do you have an idea on how to proceed?

Can you modify your original proof to get $c\in(a, b) $ instead of $c\in[a, b] $? I have seen this done earlier on this website, but don't have the reference right away.

@SineoftheTime: thanks for your answer, not sure if I fully got it though. My goal is not to prove the "MVT for derivatives" but to prove the "MVT for integrals". The goals is also to show that different proofs result in different intervals for c.

@ParamanandSingh: I have attempted it but the EVT does not necessarily hold in the interval $(a,b)$. If you find it, feel free to point me to it :)
